# Pandas - Values as percentage for of each Column

Tags: pandas, percentage

I am still a beginner and I just came across this problem.

I have a dataframe with 78 rows × 138 columns that looks like this:

```
        2009-01     2009-02     2009-03     2009-04     ...
name1       1           1           3           1   
name2       0           1           1           1
name3       1           1           1           0
```

I want something like

```
        2009-01     2009-02     2009-03     2009-04     ...
name1       50%         33%         60%         50%     
name2       0           33%         20%         50%
name3       50%         33%         20%         0
```

It looks easy but I am struggling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by `sum` with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and then multiple by `100` - output are numeric values:

```
df1 = df.div(df.sum()).mul(100).round()
print (df1)
       2009-01  2009-02  2009-03  2009-04
name1     50.0     33.0     60.0     50.0
name2      0.0     33.0     20.0     50.0
name3     50.0     33.0     20.0      0.0
```

If need all values percentages:

```
df = df.div(df.sum()).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str).add('%')
print (df)
      2009-01 2009-02 2009-03 2009-04
name1     50%     33%     60%     50%
name2      0%     33%     20%     50%
name3     50%     33%     20%      0%
```

And if want to add percentages for all values without `0` (used `0` like string for all strings data) :

```
df3 = df.div(df.sum()).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str).add('%').mask(df.eq(0), '0')
print (df3)
      2009-01 2009-02 2009-03 2009-04
name1     50%     33%     60%     50%
name2       0     33%     20%     50%
name3     50%     33%     20%       0
```